# ddclient - wont update Invalid Keyword for 'ip' =

Tags: dyndns, ddclient

/etc/ddclient.conf

```
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.org/, web-skip='IP Address'
protocol=easydns
ssl=yes
server=members.easydns.com
login=stueng
password='****'
home.***.**
```

EDIT:

I no longer get the keyword error now after waiting a few hours. However, I still have an issue

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1023502/

The above looks succesfull to me, however I am not seeing an update in easydns and I cannot resolve the address to the correct address

can I get additional debug info out of this to make sure its succesfull?

Comment: The error message mentions `/var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache`, and that's where the invalid value. Can you try renaming or changing that file (as it's under `/var/cache/`, it should be safe to delete it, but better be on the safe side...). It looks like, for some reason, ddclient.conf is being cached under `/var/cache/`.

Comment: I recommend opening a new question about the new issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this just started to work magically a few hours later

/shrug

Comment: Was there an update for `ddclient` that fixed this?

Comment: nah, it just started to work after a few hours of leaving it be

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have p5-IO-Socket-SSL-1.48, there was a problem with the p5-IO-Socket-SSL-1.48 FreeBSD port.
Upgrading the port to 1.49 seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: How does that affect `ddclient` and what is the exact issue - link please?